# execute a php page in another php-html page on a button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code is

### menu.php

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(i) {
      var hed = document.getElementById("hed");
      switch (i) {
        case 'a':
          hed.src = "header.php";
          break;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" value="Previous-Day" onClick="changeImage('a');"> Type of Index:
    <img id="hed">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### header.php code is as below

```
<?php

echo "alpha";

?>
```

The issue is, "alpha" message is not displaying when menu.php is executed. (Instead, Image not found icon is displayed). my intention is just to display the message "alpha", what should i do to achieve that in the above code? –

Comment: You are not sending image from server... I is just a text...

Comment: Indeed in your header.php you have to use a library like GD2 to create and display an image. Or redirect a URL where the image is located.

Comment: my intention is just to display the message "alpha", what should i do to achieve that in the above code?

Comment: Don't put the message alpha in the src of an image it wont work. Instead create a div and set it as the innerHTML of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function loadXMLDoc(id)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById(id).src=xmlhttp.responseText;
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function changeImage(i) {
  var hed = document.getElementById("hed");
  switch (i) {
    case 'a':
      loadXMLDoc(hed);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

   </script>
```

Comment: Still doesn't change the fact that the text "alpha" is not a valid source for the image tag.

Comment: yes i m little bit buzi right now.. doing this challenge after some minute .:)

Comment: @DharmendraSingh, i meant to say, i want achieve the output with  minor changes in my code, but your updated solution is also not working.

Comment: Tell me the issue what is going wrong..? put the whole code if possible.